# Oscillation of $|\sum_{k =1}^N \beta_k e^{i\lambda_k x}|$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, asymptotics

Let $\lambda_k$, $k = 1, \dots, N$ be distinct real numbers. Then the functions $e^{i\lambda_1 x}, \dots, e^{i\lambda_N x}$ are linearly independent on, say, the interval $(0,\infty)$. So for any complex numbers $\beta_k$, $k = 1, \dots, N$ not all zero, the function

$$g(x):= \sum_{k =1}^N \beta_k e^{i\lambda_k x}$$

does not vanish identically on $(0,\infty)$. Does there exist some fixed $c > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ so that
$$ |g(x_n)| \ge c, \qquad \mbox{for all $n$?}$$

This is easily verifiable in simple cases such as $g(x) = e^{i\lambda x} +  e^{-i\lambda x} = 2\cos(\lambda x)$ ($\lambda \neq 0$), but I am unsure whether it holds in general because I don't see how to select the $x_n$ when there are many different competing frequencies.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure I get the question - do you want to show that given $g$ as above, $g(x)$ doesn't go to zero as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: @Conrad Yes that is what I want to show and is equivalent to my statement above.

Comment: thought so, but wanted to make sure as the statement $g$ doesn't go to zero at infinity seems simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove that $g$ is quasi-periodic in the sense that for any fixed real $y$, there is $x_n(y) \to \infty$ st $g(x_n(y)) \to g(y)$ so the result follows unless $g$ is identically zero and that as noted in the post is impossible.

Note first that $|\sin x - \sin y| \le 2|x-y|$ for real $x,y$ and same with $\cos$ so $|e^{ix}-e^{iy}| \le 4|x-y|$

But by Dirichlet approximation theorem there is $x_n(y) \to \infty$ and $q_n(y)$ integers st $|\frac{\lambda_k (x_n(y)-y)}{2\pi} - q_n(y)| \le \frac{1}{n}, k=1,...,N$ which means by the above inequality

$|e^{i\lambda_k (x_n(y)-y)}-1| \le \frac{8\pi}{n}, k=1,..,N$, so

$|g(x_n(y))-g(y)|\le \sum_{k=1,N} |\beta_k| |e^{iy}|e^{i\lambda_k (x_n(y)-y)}-1| \le \frac{8\pi BN}{n}$ where $B=\max_{k=1,N}|\beta_k|$, hence $g(x_n(y)) \to g(y)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a few questions. First, do we have $|\sin x - \sin y| \le |x - y|$ as $\sin x - \sin y = \int_y^x \cos(s)ds$? Second, could you explain a little more how you choose the $x_n(y)$ and why they diverges to infinity? I looked up several versions of the Dirichlet approximation theorem and I'm not sure which one you are using. One version says that give finitely many numbers $x_1, \dots x_m$ and $\delta > 0$, one can find a positive integer $q$ such that each of the numbers $qx_1, \dots, qx_2$ differs from some integer by less than $\delta$.

Comment: First estimate sure we can lower the constant to $1$ but that is irrelevant; dirichlet says that we can choose such in any interval $[r, n^Nr]$ for positive $r$ by the usual pigeonhole principle, so we can choose $x_1$ then $x_2 \ge x_1+1$ etc (where we choose a $w_1$ in dirichlet for $\lambda_k/(2\pi)$ and then $x_1=w_1+y$ etc)