# Oscillation of $\sin(1/x) - \sum_{k=1}^N \beta_k x^{i\lambda_k}$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, asymptotics

Let $\lambda_k$, $k = 1, \dots, N$ be distinct real numbers, and let $\beta_k$, $k = 1, \dots, N$ be complex numbers not all zero. I would like to know if the function

$$g(x) = \sin(1/x) - \sum_{k=1}^N \beta_k x^{i\lambda_k}, \qquad x \in (0,\infty), $$

does not go to zero as $x \to \infty$. Using complex exponentials, we can rewrite $g$ as
$$g(x) = \frac{e^{i/x} - e^{-i/x}}{2i} - \sum_{k=1}^N \beta_k e^{i\lambda_k \ln x}.$$

One would then like to appeal to something like, e.g., [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114118/oscillation-of-sum-k-1n-beta-k-ei-lambda-k-x-as-x-to-infty) on the oscillation of linearly independent complex exponentials. However, this does not seem immediately applicable. The different rates at which $1/x$ and $\ln x$ tend to $\infty$, respectively $-\infty$, make the oscillations difficult to compare.

For some context, showing that $g(x)$ does not go to zero is related to showing that $\sin(1/x)$ is *not* a so-called polyhomogeneous conormal function, which is a certain natural class of functions to consider on a manifold with corners.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(1/x)- \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k x^{i\lambda_k}\ne 0$$ because
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(e^t)e^{-\pi r^{-2}(t-m)^2}dt =0$$

And
with $$f(t)=
\sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k e^{2i\pi (\lambda_1-\lambda_k) t}$$
we have that for $r$ large enough
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-\pi r^{-2}(t-m)^2}dt=r\sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k 
e^{-\pi r^2(\lambda_1-\lambda_k)^2} e^{-2i\pi m (\lambda_1-\lambda_k)}
$$
stays non-zero as $m\to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had asked the question incorrectly. I want to understand the oscillation as $x \to 0$. I edited the question.

Comment: Apply the same method. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(e^t)e^{-\pi r^{-2}(t-m)^2}dt \to 0$ as $m\to \infty$ so you can remove it.

Comment: I am trying to fill in some of the details of your answer. It seems you are setting $x = e^{-m}$ and sending $m \to \infty$. Could you explain the relationship of these integrals to $g(e^{-m})$ as $m \to \infty$? Also, I don't see how to show the claim about the integral of $\sin(e^t)$ against the Gaussian approaching $0$. If $\sin(e^t)$ is replaced by a constant, then this integral is independent of $m$. Is there an integration by parts used here?

Comment: Yes you can do an integration by parts, write $h(t)=-\int_t^\infty \sin(e^y)dy$ as some sort of alternating series so you can bound it by its first term which is smaller and smaller as $t\to \infty$, this implies that $\lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t) (e^{-\pi r^{-2}(t-m)^2})'dt =0$

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I find this approach interesting and I am trying to fill in all the steps. Could you explain more, e.g., how the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(e^t) e^{- \pi r^{-2}(t- m)^2}dt$ relates to the value $\sin(e^m)$? I tried to show that the integral converges to this value as $r \to \infty$, but it seems we actually want to send $r \to 0$ to get this (so that the Gaussian becomes more concentrated around $t = m$).